# Find the smallest positive value taken by $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, diophantine-equations

> Find the smallest positive value taken by $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ for positive integers $a,b,c$. Find all integers $a,b,c$ which give the smallest value.

Since it is generally hard to find the minimum of a multivariate polynomial, I tried factoring it at first. The $abc$ reminds me of AM-GM, but I wasn't sure how to relate the $a^3+b^3+c^3$ to it. Also the condition that we are working with integers may make it easier to find the minimum.

Comment: It factors as $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)$

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049581___

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $4$, for $a = 1, b = 1, c = 2$ (or some permutation).

We have 
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a + b + c)[(a + b + c)^2 - 3(ab + bc + ca)].$$
This shows that any positive value taken by the expression must be at least as large as $a + b + c$, which leaves only the above cases and $a =b = c = 1$ to examine.

**Edit** Let $A = a^3 - 3abc + b^3 + c^3$. We will write $A$ in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials. The leading term in lexicographic order is $a^3$, so we compute
$$A - (a + b + c)^3 = - 3a^2b - 3a^2 c - 3ab^2 - 9abc - 3ac^2 - 3b^2 c.$$
The leading term in this expression is $-3a^2b$, so we compute
$$A - (a + b + c)^3 + 3(a + b + c)(ab + ac + bc) = 0.$$

Comment: Firstly how did you know that factorization? Secondly how do you know it must be at least as large as $a+b+c$?

Comment: @user19405892 There is a standard method for writing symmetric polynomials in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials $\sigma_1 = a + b + c$, $\sigma_2 = ab + bc + ca$, $\sigma_3 = abc$. It can be applied here. For the second question, when $r$ and $s$ are two positive integers, we must have $rs \geq r$.

Comment: How do you know that $(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca) > 0$?

Comment: Let $R = a + b + c$ and $S = (a + b + c)^2 - 3(ab + bc + ca)$. You are looking for the smallest positive value taken by $RS$. We know that $R > 0$. Therefore we are interested only in cases where $S > 0$. In those cases, $RS \geq R$. This proves that *if* $RS$ is positive, then $RS \geq R$. Since we know that $RS$ can take the value $4$, we need only prove that $RS$ cannot be $1, 2, 3$ and show that $RS$ is $4$ only in the cases stated. Since $RS \geq R$, the only cases we need to look at are where $R \leq 4$.

Comment: Once you see that the minimum is at least a+b+c you can tell that the min is at least 4, because a+b+c is at least 3, but a+b+c=3 only when a=b=c=1,but if a=b=c the expression is 0.

Answer (score 3):

$$\quad F=a^3+b^3+c^3-3 a b c=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2- a b -b c- c a)=$$ $$= \frac {1}{2}(a+b+c)(\;[a-b]^2+[b-c]^2+[c-a]^2\;).$$
 If $a=b=c$ then $F=0.$

If $a,b,c$ are not all equal then $a+b+c\geq 1+1+2=4,$ and also at least two of $|a-b|, |b-c|, |c-a|$ are non-zero, giving $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 1^2+1^2+0^2=2 .$

Therefore $F>0\implies F\geq \frac {1}{2}(2)(4)=4.$ Which is attained when $a=b=1$ and $c=2.$

Comment: This polynomial has shown up in so many problems that some of us have learned a lot about it.